# Pyserial scale connection

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to send commands and read data from a KERN scale. I have an online manual: [DOC](https://dok.kern-sohn.com/manuals/files/English/KCP-ZB-e-v1.3.7.pdf). I can successfully read the data if I place something on the scale. However my application requires data at certain times, not after something was placed on the scale.
The manual says that if you send the ascii encoded "S \r\n" command it answers with the latest stable weight.
My code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/tty.usbserial-1140',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0
)

count = 1


def format_cmd(cmd):
    return cmd.encode('ascii')


command = format_cmd('S \r\n')
ser.write(command)

while True:
    for line in ser.read():
        print(chr(line), end='')
        count = count+1
```

The output from the scale: SBvæf¶;k

If I send only the letter S as a command the output is better: SST,GS 0.059kg

I think there is something wrong with the encoding, but according to the documentation it should send a different responses both times.

Comment: I don't think that S and space is a command. Did you mean SI?

Comment: Why are you putting a space after the `S` command?  I don't see anything in the document you linked to suggest that the space is necessary here - although I would expect an error reply rather than garbage if it was actually causing a problem.

Comment: I also tried SI and it returned the gibberish, but as I understand the command format requires a space after the <CMD>. If you check point 1.2 in the docs there is a space right after the cmd.

Comment: SI without space: S £cvæV¶;k

Comment: 1.2 refers to the need for a space to separate arguments.  1.4 shows S and SI without a space.

Comment: Also did you mean: `print(str(line))`?

Comment: It returns the same garbage with or without the space. I think chr(line) works fine, otherwise I wouldn’t be able to get the data after I place something on the scale.